# How can I use apply here?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css to customize my menu. I have a bunch of buttons and I want to change the first letter of each button's content to show the linked shortcut. This is used by Blizzard in Warcraft3:

[image: warcraft3 menu]

Tailwind's docs provide a [button example](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/examples/buttons/#simple). It works as expected.

To change the color of my letter. I can use the css pseudo element [first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter).

But, there is a problem (or I would not be here). `apply` works in the tailwind example but not with my custom css. Does `apply` only, well, apply to tailwind's own css? What did I miss?

```css
 .btn {
    @apply font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded; /* works as expected */
  }
  .btn-blue {
    @apply bg-blue text-white; /* works as expected */
  }
  .btn-blue:hover {
    @apply bg-blue-dark; /* works as expected */
  }
  
.btn::first-letter {
  font-size: 130%; /* works as expected */
  @apply bg-orange; /* nope */
}

div::first-letter {
  font-size: 130%; /* works as expected */
  @apply bg-orange; /* nope */
}

div {
  @apply bg-red; /* nope */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Using utilities: -->
<button class="bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
  Button
</button>

<!-- Extracting component classes: -->
<button class="btn btn-blue">
  Button
</button>


<div>
sd
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm0c4xe8/) to mess around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@apply` is not CSS. It is a [TailwindCSS directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/#apply) that will change your CSS. But this is not possible using the CDN variant of TailwindCSS as stated here in the [TailwindCSS installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#cdn) (emphasis theirs)

> Before getting started please note, **many of the features that make
>   Tailwind CSS great are not available using the CDN builds.** To take
>   full advantage of Tailwind's features, install Tailwind via npm.

The @apply is just ignored by CSS. If you carefully inspect the CSS in your browsers you would see that the classes `.btn` and `.btn-blue` have no effect whatsoever.